# Help on how to write a function to be used with NMinimize

Tags: functions

I need some help to write a proper function to be used as a parameter on NMinimize.  Here is the code of the function to be minimized (Please correct, optimize and rewrite the code if you want to - I need to understand how to write proper Mathematica code).

```
plot[τ_, Ω_] := Module[{arg, abs, aux}, 
   {arg, abs} = 
     Factor[Together[ComplexExpand[Through[{Arg, Abs}[(1 + I*2*Ω)/(1 + I*2*τ*Ω)]]]]]; 
   aux = arg/Degree;
   aux = If[aux < 0, aux = 360 - aux, aux];
   {aux, 20*Log10[abs]}]

modFunction1[kc_, gp_, ω_, pm_, variable_:s] := Module[{arg, abs, aux}, 
  {arg, abs} = 
    Factor[Together[ComplexExpand[Through[{Arg, Abs}[kc*gp /. variable -> I*ω]]]]]; 
  aux = (-arg)*(180/Pi) + pm - 180;
  aux = If[aux < 0, 360 + aux, aux];
  {-20*Log10[abs], aux}]; 

functionF1[kc_, gp_, ω_, pm_, variable_:s, τ_, Ω_] := Module[{a, b, c, d}, 
  {a, b} = N[modFunction1[kc, gp, ω, pm, variable]];
  {d, c} = N[plot[τ, Ω]];
  (a - c)^2 + (b - d)^2];
```

and finally

```
NMinimize[functionF1[50, 100/(s*(s + 5)*(s + 10)), 9, 42, τ, Ω],
  {{τ, 10.5, 10.6}, {Ω, -0.1988, -0.1987}}]
```

NMinimize returns

> NMinimize::nnum: "The function value 0.000459846 +(54.9326 -aux$584644)^2 is not a number at {[Tau],[CapitalOmega]} = {10.5919,-0.198714}"

but evaluating functionF1 on those same values returns a real number.

What am I missing?  Any comment on how to write the code is most welcome.  I definitely need some guide on how to write proper functions.

Comment: You need to rewrite your function such that there are only numeric arguments. If you need to work with symbolic variables then do this outside of NMinimize, i.e., calculate your objective function.

Comment: In `plot` you write `aux = If[aux < 0, aux = 360 - aux, aux];`. Perhaps you meant to write `aux = If[aux < 0, 360 + aux, aux]` as you did in `modFunction1`?

Comment: `functionF1[kc_, gp_, \[Omega]_, pm_, 
 variable_: s, \[Tau]_?NumericQ, \[CapitalOmega]_?NumericQ]` so that it stays symbolic for non-numeric arguments, and you get `{1.33561*10^-13, {\[Tau] -> 10.5662, \[CapitalOmega] -> -0.198671}}`

Comment: @Rojo - Many thanks - I have changed all the other functions to accomodate ?NumericQ where it is needed and Mathematica had not problem to find the minimum (it took some time though).

Comment: @Rolf - Many thanks.

Comment: @m_goldberg - Thanks for pointing out my mistake and for editing the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm putting the comments into an answer, the gist of it is very simple: The arguments in the function you need to minimize should be numeric. The trick with `NumericQ` that is suggested is covered [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/731) and [here](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/3820).